# Dependent Observables

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm am writing a Windows 8 app.  In it, I have a combo box with distances / radiuses in it.  i.e., 1 mile, 2 miles, 5 miles etc.

However, I would like the distance unit to change between kilometres and miles depending on user preferences.

On the PreferencesViewModel I can have a simple enum property which defines the distance unit.

On the Main ViewModel, I can have an ObservableCollection which contains the range of radiuses.
So when the Main ViewModel initialises I can just populate this with the radiuses and in the XAML view, I can have a ValueConverter which simply converts the combination of the distance unit from the preferences with the current item to "1 mile", "3 kilometres" etc.

However, the user can bring up the UI controlling the preferences at any time and concurrently.  It would be great to be able to refresh this ComboBox at the same time the user changes the preference.

So I'm looking for a way to create a dependent observable.  In KnockoutJs, I would just create a computed observable which essentially watches both the ObservableCollection and the user preference selection.

What's the best way to do this with C#?

Comment: I think you want the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://jesseliberty.com/2012/06/28/c-5making-inotifypropertychanged-easier/) interface

Comment: I totally agree with @JMK here. Since your are already using MVVM, you should be able to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged`-event for your selected unit. When the value is changed, simply raise the `PropertyChanged` for all affected values, which will cause your GUI to update.

Comment: OK, in that case I'll create a special event "DistanceUnitChanged" inside the Preferences VM and have the other view model listen for that change and propagate a PropertyChanged event from that ViewModel so the ComboBox re-binds and the value converter changes the labels.  I just wondered whether there was some other more elegant way to do it.  I'm creating a special case event for the distance unit changed so that it avoids having to check what property name changed. thanks for your help.